# Can the word "shouter" be used for someone that gives a shout out to something?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice

Can the word "shouter" be used for someone that gives a shout out to something or reviews something or tells people about it to make it famous?

Comment: No, not really. Perhaps promoter, proclaimer, advocate, evangelist …

Comment: We used to have *[town] **criers*** and *[fairground] **barkers***, but I don't think ***shouter*** has ever been part of mainstream English. It's practically bound to have had various "domain-specific" usages over the centuries though.

Comment: No, but maybe a *shouter-outer*? (No, not really.)

Comment: Jake, it's not clear what you're asking. What is that "something" you're referring to? Have you got examples? Is it in a modern setting?

Comment: @bib: No, [really!](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22shouter-outer%22) :)

Comment: @bib Or maybe "out-shouter" :-)

Answer (score 2):

**A Town Crier** (for further information see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Town_crier))

> Formerly a court official, now a person employed to make public
>   announcements in the streets or marketplace of a town.

**A Barker**, a fairground/circus barker [(Cambridge)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/barker)

> a person who advertises an activity at a public event by calling out
>   to people who are walking past: a fairground/circus barker

**Ring-master**, or **compere**, or **master of ceremonies** is appointed for an occasion, performance or event.

Answer (score 0):

If the endorsement is less than honest or the promoter has an interest in the reviewed item, you might consider *[shill](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=shill)*

> One who publicly promotes another's cause, especially in an extravagant or misleading way.

*American Heritage*

The term is often used for a person posing as a neutral member of an audience but is really in league with the barker or auctioneer selling the product.

Comment: Nice word: it is in the Concise OED marked *NAmerican.* The Br Eng **plant** #3 -a person placed in a group as spy or informer, is used similarly.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to those giving a Shout-Out, one could be called an Out-Shouter. This would describe them well enough to distinguish from people who just talk at high volume or mean to distract or annoy.

EC

Answer (score 0):

It is non-standard English, but it is similar to a word I used to describe an abusive boss: "Yeller". He was a Yeller, I was the one he yelled at. The meaning is clear but to me it has two contexts: A child who talks loud or throws fits, or an adult bully who thinks shouting gets things done faster. The second case is not a positive adjective. If someone told me I was going to meet a shouter, I'd be hesitant to meet them.